# change the button value and color on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am training in PHP laravel web development

But I have two small tasks in the Frontend, and I don't have the time to learn the Frontend to get them done, please help with solving them.

I have 4 button and 1 p:

```
       <button> trans('navbar.Students')</buttom>
       <button> trans('navbar.Schools')</buttom>
       <button> trans('navbar.teachers')</buttom>
       <button> trans('navbar.teachers')</buttom>

                       <p> </p>
```

I want the following:
When the user presses one of the buttons:

```
   1- Change the button color.
   2- Putting the value of the button that was pressed in <p>.
```

- example someone clicks button1:
  The button color will change to blue, and the p value will be

  Students

Comment: Not related to Laravel / PHP, and where is your CSS and JS?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".my-button");
var para = document.querySelector("#my-para");

buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    select(i);
    para.innerHTML = button.innerHTML;
  });
});

function select(num) {
  buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
    if (i === num) return button.classList.add("active");
    button.classList.remove("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">AAA</button>
<button class="my-button">BBB</button>
<button class="my-button">CCC</button>
<button class="my-button">DDD</button>
<p id="my-para"></p>
```

---

This is an old answer but coming back to it, I wanted to show a way to keep the answer selected even after reloading the page, using just JavaScript. The solution lies in using `localStorage`. (it doesn't work in Stack Snippets, so use [this Jsitor link](https://jsitor.com/1grDofbLA))

Comment: Excellent answer keeping in mind the *reset* for a better UI.

Comment: thank you it helpful, but after refresh, all of those is reset, can I  save the page status after refresh? because the button links on navbar ,and when someone clicks on it the status is changed

Comment: @Jades you can use your PHP for that, echo class "active" if they selected it

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the ***button*** nodeList, add an event listener.

Set up a function to run a for loop to compare the index of each loop. Make sure the current iterations classlist is not undefined *(if it is undefined, it will throw an error)*. By default remove the background color for when selections change, check to see if the indexes match, if so add BG color and set p tags textContent to the textContent of the current button using a class that has the background-color and color rule set.

```js
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
const display = document.querySelector('#display')

const setSelection = (btnEl, index, parEl) => {
  for (let key in btnEl) {
    if (btnEl[key].classList !== undefined) {
      btnEl[key].classList.remove('blue')
      if (index == key) {
        btnEl[key].classList.add('blue')
        parEl.textContent = btnEl[key].textContent
      }
    }
  }
}

button.forEach((btn, i) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     setSelection(button,i,display)
  })
})
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Value 1</button>
<button class="btn">Value 2</button>
<button class="btn">Value 3</button>
<button class="btn">Value 4</button>

<p id="display"></p>
```

Comment: That `undefined` check is unnecessary as the `classList` of an element with no class is just a `classList` with a length of 0. Also, this answer is *almost identical* to mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with javascript, here is the example :

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(item){
   item.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.target.style.background = 'red';
      e.target.setAttribute('value', 'yourValue');
   });
});
```

Comment: Use rather `classList` with `toggle`, `add`, etc. instead (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66997191/383904). Styling should not be part of JS, but for CSS.

Comment: Yes i know, i just give some example with javascript for understanding the event listener.

Comment: Also, always use  `Event.currentTarget`. Use `Event.target` only when you really know whaat you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution:

```js
function go(theButton){
    theButton.style.background = 'blue';
  theButton.style.color = 'white';
    document.getElementById("gg").textContent=theButton.textContent;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="go(this)"> Students</button>
<button onclick="go(this)"> Schools</button>
<button onclick="go(this)"> teachers</button>
<button onclick="go(this)"> teachers</button>

<p id="gg"> </p>
```

Comment: Don't use inline JavaScript `on*` handlers - same as you hopefully don't use inline CSS `style` attributes. Scripts and styles should be in their related files or tags. Also, in your example there's no option to reset the previous buttons states, which makes it a weird UI.